# How I Know the Output Image Shape before putting it into Linear Layer in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, l1=120, l2=84):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, l1) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(l1, l2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(l2, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

16 is the number of Activation Map After convolution .
I don't understand in  self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, l1) How 5 came ?
Does any formula for calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

The total feature size output from the conv layers depends on the input size. It's not immediately clear from the model itself, but the code you posted works with an input size of `(bs, 3, 32, 32)`.

The model would not work with any other input size. This is why using `AdaptiveMaxPool2d` is generally preferred over fixed size pooling.

Comment: If my input size is (1 , 3 , 28 , 28) then how the 5 x 5 the output size has came ? Does any formula for calculating the output size ?

Comment: The model as written will only work for an input of size `(bs, 3, 32, 32)`. This is because the two conv/pool layers map a tensor of size `(bs, 3, 32, 32)` to a tensor of size `(bs, 16, 5, 5)`. You can look at the [Conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) and [MaxPool2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html) documentation to see how the output size relates to the input size.